# Как получить все возможные комбинации из элементов одномерного массива?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив заранее не известное величины [1,2,3....], как получить все возможные сочетания?
Результат должен быть следующим:
['12', '13', '23']

ps возможно есть варианты без использования, загружающих мозг и машину, рекурсий?

Comment: все возможные длины = 2 без учета порядка, или что? алгоритмы вроде все довольно известны, неужели вы не смогли найти решение самостоятельно?

Comment: Это как это список всех возможных сочетаний вдруг оказался состоящим только из '12', '13', '23'? Опишите нормально, что за список вам надо получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
$array=[1,2,3,4,5];

foreach($array as $v1){
    foreach($array as $v2){
        $result[$v1.$v2]=true;
    }   
}

echo implode(',',array_keys($result));
```